# Facebook Page Plugin Not Showing Up Sometimes

Tags: javascript, wordpress, facebook

We've recently updated one of our client's facebook feeds to use the newer [Facebook Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) and several times they've emailed us, saying they can't see it. The last time I updated it so that we *weren't* using a Facebook app with the plugin. I've looked at it in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari (mac and iphone) and I can see it. Googling this, I can't find anything about this particular problem.

It's in the [sidebar of the homepage](http://completelykids.org/) under the first heading "Recent Posts". The website is using Wordpress 3.6.1. (I want to update it, but that's not my call...)

This code (JavaScript SDK?) is directly under the body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src ="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And this code is the actual plugin:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/CompletelyKids1" data-width="100%" data-height="300px" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true">
<div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
<blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/CompletelyKids1">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/CompletelyKids1">Completely KIDS</a>
</blockquote></div></div>
```

My question is why wouldn't it be showing up for them? Would it be a browser problem (IE) or computer problem on their end? Is there something in the code that could prevent it from showing up on some devices/browsers? Should I be using a Facebook app for this?

Thanks!

Update: I had the client delete cache and they can see it (ha).

07/06/15 Update: So now she can't see it again, but I can as well as one of my co-workers.

Comment: Chrome console shows a warning saying, _“Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id.”_ // Did this problem already exist before you decided not to use an app id in the SDK initialization?

Comment: @CBroe: Yes. The first time they couldn't see it, it still had the app id.

Comment: @ThemesCreator: Thanks! I had them delete cache and they can see it now.

Comment: You're welcome! I have deleted the comment and put it as answer, please mark it as correct asnswer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe they have javascript deactivate or need to delete the cache

Comment: I have Javascript activated and caching turned of; and it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I keep running in to is that in order for it to show, the user seeing the page needs to be logged in to facebook at the same time. That is really annoying because if they are not logged in then all I see is a white box empty. I do this on multiple browsers, clear cache, etc, only way it works is when I'm logged in to my account.

Answer (score 0):

make sure page is published.

**Facebook Page > Settings > General > Page visibility > Page published**

and remove country restrictions:

**Facebook Page > Settings > General > Country restrictions > Page is visible to everyone**

Last one solved problem. It was set to only allow one country and even in that country the page plugin was not visible -_-

Answer (score 0):

You are right...

1. First, go to the Page published:

Facebook Page > Settings > General > Page visibility > Page published

2. Then remove country restrictions:

Facebook Page > Settings > General > Country restrictions > Page is visible to everyone